# "Running setup.py install for pefile ... error"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Trying to install PyInstaller fails on the pefile dependency step, says error and gives no information, just a wall of empty space for some reason in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running as administrator and then doing:

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```